# Python change calculator

Tags: python

I need to create a program that will input a money amount in the form of a floating point number. The program will then calculate which dollars and coins to make this amount. Coins will be preferred in the least number of coins. If any of the values is zero, I need to not output the value. IE: if the change is 26 cents you only need to tell the user they will receive 1 quarter and 1 penny. No more, no less.

Below is what I have so far, the only thing I cant figure out is to make the program not output the zero values

```
# calculate amount of change needed

dollar = 100
quarter = 25
dime = 10
nickel = 5
penny = 1

def main():

    calc = True

    while calc:
    
    
        lst = []
        mon = ['dollars', 'quaters', 'dimes', 'nickels', 'pennys']
       
        doll = 0
        quart = 0
        dimes = 0
        nick = 0
        pen = 0
        

        total = int(float(input('Enter amount of change: '))*100)

        amount = total
    

        while amount - dollar >= 0:
            amount -= dollar
            doll += 1

        while amount - quarter >= 0:
            amount -= quarter
            quart += 1

        while amount - dime >= 0:
            amount -= dime
            dimes += 1

        while amount - nickel >= 0:
            amount -= nickel
            nick += 1

        while amount - penny >= 0:
            amount -= penny
            pen += 1
        
        lst.append(doll)
        lst.append(quart)
        lst.append(dimes)
        lst.append(nick)
        lst.append(pen)
        
        print('\nThe change owed is: ')
        
        print(" ")
        
        for i, e in zip(lst, mon):
            print(i, e)

        calc = input("\nPress 'Y' to try again or any other key to exit: ")
        if calc != 'y' and calc != 'Y':
            calc = False
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

else:
    pass
```

Comment: You need to change your while loops with subtraction to compare against the change variables. For example, use `while amount >= dollar:`

Comment: Hint: you already have the pseudocode for this buried in your question: `If any of the values is zero, I need to not output the value.`      AKA: `IF VALUE IS ZERO, then SKIP THAT VALUE`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving it

```
 if doll >= 1:
        lst.append(doll)
        mon.append("dollars")
        
    if quart >= 1:
        lst.append(quart)
        mon.append("quarters")
    if dimes >= 1:
        lst.append(dimes)
        mon.append("dimes")
    if nick >= 1:
        lst.append("nickles")
    if pen >= 1:
        lst.append(pen)
        mon.append("pennies")
```

this seems to have worked